# What are those "unknown" services listed by nmap?

Tags: services, nmap

I run `nmap` on a Lubuntu machine using its own private IP address.

What are those "unknown" services?

How can I find them out? Is `fuser` supposed to find that out?

Thanks.

```
$ nmap -p0-65535 192.168.1.198

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-19 23:32 EDT
Nmap scan report for olive.fios-router.home (192.168.1.198)
Host is up (0.00050s latency).
Not shown: 65526 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
111/tcp   open     rpcbind
139/tcp   open     netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open     microsoft-ds
2049/tcp  open     nfs
5900/tcp  filtered vnc
41441/tcp open     unknown
43877/tcp open     unknown
44847/tcp open     unknown
55309/tcp open     unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.22 seconds
```

Comment: Related: [How can I find out information about a service?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/505538)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are those "unknown" services?

Those services are "unknown" because they are not listed in `nmap`'s `services` file, nmap uses that to map port numbers to services. On my system, `nmap` uses `/usr/share/nmap/nmap-services`.

I found out  where the file is located by doing (I am on devuan, a debian-based system like ubuntu or mint):

```
$ dpkg -L nmap
```

On RedHat/Suse based systems, you use `rpm -ql nmap`.

> How can I find them out? Is fuser supposed to find that out?

`fuser` is `nmap`'s friend, for each, simply run `fuser <port>/<protocol>` (the first column of what `nmap` prints out):

```
$ fuser 41441/tcp
41441/tcp 1234
```

This will give you the pid of the process (above example, 1234) which you can pass to `ps`

```
 $ ps 1234

 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1234 ?        Sl   169:39 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dnop -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager [...]
```

In my example, it is actually Apache Tomcat ...

Now, I searched for 41441 in `/usr/share/nmap/nmap-services` and replaced the "unknown" with "tomcat":

```
tomcat        41441/tcp
```

Now, nmap detects my tomcat:

```
$ nmap -p0-65535 192.168.1.198

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-19 23:32 EDT
Nmap scan report for olive.fios-router.home (192.168.1.198)
Host is up (0.00050s latency).
Not shown: 65526 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
111/tcp   open     rpcbind
139/tcp   open     netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open     microsoft-ds
2049/tcp  open     nfs
5900/tcp  filtered vnc
41441/tcp open     tomcat
```